# jQuery pseudo code for selecting nth elelment not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this `table`, for which, for each row of it, I want to select the second `td`. I know the easiest way, (or at least one way) to do this, is use `each()` and loop for all `tr` and select/store the second `td` in some variable, inside the each loop.

But I was thinking if there could be a direct pseudo code that could help me do this direct without any kinda loop, may it be `each()` or whatever.

When I do this..

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdSelectedCloth > tbody > tr > td')
```

It gives me all `td(s)` (near about 40, 8 rows, 5 cols each)

when I do this..

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdSelectedCloth > tbody > tr > td:odd')
```

It gives me half `td(s)` the odd ones,

when I do this

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdSelectedCloth > tbody > tr > td:even')
```

Again, same it gives me 20 `td(s)`, the even one.

but when I do this

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdSelectedCloth > tbody > tr > td:2')
```

It says `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: 2`

But when I do this..

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdSelectedCloth > tbody > tr > td:eq(2)')
```

It only shows one `td`??? And just for the first row, I mean, if I apply pseudo code `:odd` or `:even`, it gives the `td(s)` for all rows, but when I do `:eq(2)` it gives the second `td` for only the first row???
So, how can I get second `td` for all rows, preferably by *not using each or any kind of loop* but *by using some sort of pseudo code?*

ps: I was running this in firefox console, just in case are wondering what says "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: 2"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdSelectedCloth tr td:nth-child(2)');  // would select all cells that are in the 2nd column
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead.

Like `td:nth-child(2)`

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/rFnUL/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdSelectedCloth > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)")
```